# Why does python "where" produce empty array even if element is in list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, where-clause

I'm pretty new to python. I produced a long list of numbers (about 6144000 elements). Then I find the smallest number with min(), and finally I want to recover the index corresponding to such number, but an empty array is returned. I copy and paste all the inputs and outputs (using Canopy):

```
**INPUT**: min(ravel(loss))

Out[89]: 1.6158025919749239e-37

**INPUT**: ind=where(loss==1.6158025919749239e-37)

**INPUT**: ind

Out[91]: (array([], dtype=int64),)

**INPUT**: type(loss)

Out[92]: list

**INPUT**: 1.6158025919749239e-37 in loss

Out[93]: True
```

What is the issue?

Comment: It may be because of print precision. try `target = min(ravel(loss))` and then `ind=where(loss== target)`

Comment: And does this work `ind = where(loss==min(loss))`?

Comment: `1.6158025919749239e-37` is the representation of the real value of minimum. But when you use `==` you should use the real value rather tan the representation of it which is basically not exactly the same as the real value.

Comment: Use `np.argmin` instead of `min` plus `where`,

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, they where all very valuable.